# Como inserir comentario no facebook pelo app iOS Swift? Não é compartilhar na minha própria timeline

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Estou tentando inserir um comentário em uma página do facebook com o meu app, mas não consegui encontrar função para isso em Swift para iOS.
Obs.: Não é escrever/postar em minha timeline.

Comment: Poste o código que já fez.

Comment: Acesse esse link no pastebin http://pastebin.com/EDmArNVG